# Did the Irish Catholic church have slaves in Ireland as recently as 1996?

Tags: catholic-church, slavery

[This article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2013/feb/05/ireland-magdalene-laundry-system-apology) covers the topic well, but is more about the Irish government admitting collusion with the supposed slave holders.

> Labelled the "Maggies", the women and girls were stripped of their names and dumped in Irish Catholic church-run laundries where nuns treated them as slaves, simply because they were unmarried mothers, orphans or regarded as somehow morally wayward.
>
> Over 74 years, 10,000 women were put to work in de facto detention, mostly in laundries run by nuns.

Were people really held as slaves? What was their treatment like?

---

Clarification:

*What is a slave?* Obviously, they were not actually considered property by anyone and it must have been underground because slavery is illegal in Ireland. But were these people basically slaves in that they were prevented from leaving at their own will and were they forced to do labor or suffer consequences (beating, no food, etc.)

I am asking the question because when google searching I see people saying things like "In 1996, Bill Clinton was president, Yahoo’s search-engine was two years old, and the Roman Catholic Church had slaves." I would think that in the least the statement is misleading because the Church as a whole did not do anything of that kind.

Comment: I do not understand what an answer to this question would look like. There was [a report](http://www.justice.ie/en/JELR/Pages/MagdalenRpt2013) published about the state involvement. It cites numbers consistent with the article above. Whether you consider the victims as "slaves" probably depends a lot on your definitions - the report does not use that word. Similarly, it isn't clear that you could say the Church had slaves.

Comment: When the article says "treated as slaves" that does not mean actual slaves. It's a figure of speech. Slavery has been illegal in Ireland for hundreds of years. If you want to know more about conditions of these women then I recommend asking at the History site.

Comment: wouldn't this be better placed in a comment?

Comment: It is actually the answer. Were these people really held as slaves? No. If the question had been whether the Maggie laundries existed and were people treated badly, that would be a different answer.

Comment: So de facto "treated as slaves" but de jure "not slaves" because it's outlawed in the host country means "not slaves"? Consequently human trafficking doesn't exist in Europe as it is outlawed. Those Ukrainian girls are just being "treated as prostitutes" but they aren't actual prostitutes? You see what I mean?

Comment: @0xC0000022L - slaves are people who are property of the owner, and can be bought or sold. These didn't seem to be.

Comment: Are you asking if these places really exist, or if the conditions were as described in the article? Asking if they were really slaves seems to be counterproductive.

Comment: @oddthinking It seems you are making a good answer anyway. Those are the kind of statements that would be helpful in an answer. I am making an edit.

Comment: See my edit. Clarifies some things.

Comment: *"it must have been underground"* Not if the reports are to be believed because the courts and executive supported the situation. *"because slavery is illegal in Ireland"* The government had simply stuck a label on the situation that said "not slaves". The situation was presumably considered to be equivalent to the incarceration of duly convicted criminals.

Comment: [*FWIW*](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/j/joni+mitchell/magdalene+laundries_20075443.html)

Comment: Strict nuns housing the wayward and making them actually work for their room and board I could believe. That the nuns and the women economically or socially trapped there could have different opinions or experiences of such an institution is entirely possible.   10,000 people begins to sound like embellishment.  Are several hundred to a thousand people at a time needed to wash clothes at a chain of laundries?

Comment: I believe that with the latest clarification, the question is about [forced labour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_labor), NOT [slavery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery). I would like to edit the question to match. If you provided a notable claim of the women ang girls being directly called slaves, that would alter the answer (from a Yes to a No).

Comment: I don't get the fuss over labels here. If you are forced to work at someone else's bidding; forced to live your life in a manner dictated by others; denied the product of your own labor; denied the freedom to leave; subject to capture and return if you leave anyway; and subject to punishment for resisting,  then the situation bears a considerable resemblance to slavery *de facto* no matter what *de jure* may be applied. With criminal sentences we expect that there should be a solemn, open, judicial process resulting in a proportionate sentence with a definite end in all but the worst cases.

Comment: According to Google: "slave; Noun A person who is the legal property of another and is forced to obey them." If the question is "Were they slaves, according to Google?", the answer is NO they were NOT slaves. Were they slaves according to Irish law? I don't know, but my money would be on NO, they were not slaves. "Were they treated as forced labour (similar to enslavement)?" The answer (based on the reports we've seen) would appear to be YES. So the fuss over labels here is critical, because it determines what the answer to the question is.

Comment: As for our expectation about judicial process, I think that is a cultural expectation. In the 1930s Ireland, apparently there was no such expectation for the treatment of the "morally wayward".

Comment: There is no notable claim there were any slaves. The article does not imply they were "slaves", just they were "treated as slaves".

Comment: @Oddthinking: That legalistic definition of "slave" as property is very narrow. [*Slave*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slave) is a fluid concept, as is [*property*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property). The ones who are in that condition don't split hairs.

Comment: Then why are we bothering to answer the question? They were slaves; they were superheroes; they were evil; they were fish. If you let words mean whatever you like, you can answer this however you like. Until we can agree on definitions, we can't agree on conclusions.

Comment: @oddthinking I think my edit shows that I am more interested in their treatment as slaves rather than being classically defined as slaves. As MikeDunlavey said it is a very fluid term, and in my experience is rarely used in the classical definition.

Comment: Ireland joined the European Union in 1976. I think its highly improbable that there slaves up till 1976. Ireland joined the Council of Europe in 1949 - the COE primarily focuses on human rights.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I think we gotta look beyond strict definitions to intentions and meanings. We're not doing algebra here.

Comment: @fredsbend: It wasn't underground. The government sanctioned it - indeed I it was often the courts/police sending people to the laundries. That is my main objection to using the word slavery. It was a legal punishment - an unjust one in many circumstances - and they were forced to work because it was widely believed that industriousness was good for morality

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's use the 1926 Slavery Convention (Geneva) definition of slavery. I'm using the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1926_Slavery_Convention) as a reference, but the contents of this convention aren't under debate here, so:

> "the status or condition of a person over whom any or all of the powers attaching to the right of ownership are exercised"

If taking someone prisoner indefinitely is considered taking ownership of them, this condition is met. This is somewhat subjective.

The accompanying definition of the slave trade:

> "all acts involved in the capture, acquisition or disposal of a person with intent to reduce him to slavery; all acts involved in the acquisition of a slave with a view to selling or exchanging him; all acts of disposal by sale or exchange of a slave acquired with a view to being sold or exchanged, and, in general, every act of trade or transport in slaves."

The women were indeed captured, acquired and reduced to slavery, so their situation seems to meet this condition, perhaps moreso than the first instance.

The UN Committee Against Torture made the following statement:

> The Committee has said that it is “gravely concerned at the failure of the State to protect girls and women who were involuntarily confined between 1922 and 1996 in the Magdalene Laundries”. [News article from thejournal.ie](http://www.thejournal.ie/un-committee-against-torture-recommends-inquiry-into-magdalene-laundries-149691-Jun2011/)

Chapter 20 of the Magdalen Final Report (more below) details the financials of some of the laundries. These demonstrate that the Laundries were being paid for work carried out by the women, for which no wages were given.

**Yes**. They can be considered slaves.

They also weren't allowed keep any children they had, which while not a distinct facet of slavery, gives an idea of the level of dehumanisation we're talking about. The Margaret Bullen article is one example.

The incarceration and forced labour was in no way underground. About 25% of hostages were delivered to the laundries by the state. I refuse to call them inmates, as I don't consider any of them criminals, and most of them weren't criminals in law either. The Gardai colluded in returning escapees and delivering hostages. The courts were also comlplicit. For your verification, I'm referring largely to the [Magdalen Final Report](http://www.idcmagdalen.ie/en/MLW/Magdalen%20Rpt%20full.pdf/Files/Magdalen%20Rpt%20full.pdf) which was released in February 2013 by the Irish Government after an extensive study. I encourage you to check it, but it is over 1,200 pages long. From the report:

> "This Report has established that approximately 10,000 women are known to
> have entered a Magdalen Laundry from the foundation of the State in 1922
> until the closure of the last Laundry in 1996. Of the cases in which routes of
> entry are known, 26.5% were referrals made or facilitated by the State. "

The women who were put into the laundries were made to work, and their work was profited from, in a way which would be illegal in "official" Irish prisons, where it would be deemed a human rights violation.

The laundries were subject to the same inspections as regular workplaces. From Chapter 12 of the report:

> "This Chapter confirms that the Magdalen Laundries were inspected by the Factories Inspectorate in the same manner as commercial (non-religious operated) laundries, again both before and after enactment of the Factories Act 1955."

Their imprisonment was also illegal for many years, though the church had the support of the Garda Siochana (Irish Police Force) who would both deliver hostages to them and return escapees.

As for the date of 1996, by this stage, admissions to Magdalene laundries were no longer part of Irish life. On one hand, we had become more enlightened and liberated as a society. On the other hand, washing machines were cheaper to use. However, up to this date there were still older women who had been taken hostage years previous. They may have been somewhat institutionalised, or otherwise had nowhere else to go, but they were still being deprived of a number of their human rights. The laundries stopped working in 1996, but some of the women had become inmates, not knowing who to integrate into society. At this point, their prison was more mental than physical.

As for the treatment of the women over the years, it was bad. They were de-humanised and subject to abuse and exploitation you wouldn't give an animal. We're talking about a combination of psychological, and often physical torture and hard labour. Some were literally worked to death. Some died later on from kidney and liver failure, as a direct result of sustained exposure to the laundry chemicals. One example is [Margaret Bullen](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/womens-politics/9878223/Irelands-Magdalene-Laundries-I-hope-my-birth-mother-can-now-rest-in-peace.html), who entered the laundries when she was 5, because her mother was unable to take care of her, and died when she was 51, still inside a convent, from `"Goodpasture Syndrome, a disease caused by inhalation of chemicals over many years resulting in end stage kidney and liver failure."`

Given that many entered into the laundries when they were children, it is relevant to consider the findings of the [Commission to Inquire into Child Abuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_to_Inquire_into_Child_Abuse). This was an investigation into the living conditions of children in state care, almost always run by monks, priests, and nuns. It doesn't particularly apply to the Laundries, but it should give you some idea of what the church in Ireland were capable of. The Ryan Report, published in 2009, came to these conclusions, among others:

> **Overall.** Physical and emotional abuse and neglect were features of the institutions. Sexual abuse occurred in many of them, particularly boys’ institutions. Schools were run in a severe, regimented manner that imposed unreasonable and oppressive discipline on children and even on staff.
>
> **Physical abuse.** The Reformatory and Industrial Schools depended on rigid control by means of severe corporal punishment and the fear of such punishment. A climate of fear, created by pervasive, excessive and arbitrary punishment, permeated most of the institutions and all those run for boys. Children lived with the daily terror of not knowing where the next beating was coming from.
>
> **Sexual abuse.** Sexual abuse was endemic in boys’ institutions. The schools investigated revealed a substantial level of sexual abuse of boys in care that extended over a range from improper touching and fondling to rape with violence. Perpetrators of abuse were able to operate undetected for long periods at the core of institutions. When confronted with evidence of sexual abuse, the response of the religious authorities was to transfer the offender to another location where, in many instances, he was free to abuse again. The safety of children in general was not a consideration. The situation in girls’ institutions was different. Although girls were subjected to predatory sexual abuse by male employees or visitors or in outside placements, sexual abuse was not systemic in girls’ schools.
>
> **Neglect.** Poor standards of physical care were reported by most male and female complainants. Children were frequently hungry and food was inadequate, inedible and badly prepared in many schools. Accommodation was cold, spartan and bleak. Sanitary provision was primitive in most boys’ schools and general hygiene facilities were poor.
>
> **Emotional abuse.** Witnesses spoke of being belittled and ridiculed on a daily basis. Private matters such as bodily functions and personal hygiene were used as opportunities for degradation and humiliation. Personal and family denigration was widespread. There was constant criticism and verbal abuse and children were told they were worthless.
>
> **Supervision by the Department of Education**. The system of inspection by the Department was fundamentally flawed and incapable of being effective. Complaints by parents and others made to the Department were not properly investigated. The Department did not apply the standards in the rules and their own guidelines when investigating complaints, but sought to protect and defend the religious Congregations and the schools. The Department dealt inadequately with complaints about sexual abuse, which were generally dismissed or ignored.

The group, Justice for Magdalenes (here Magdalenes, which is sometimes shortened to Maggies, refers to victims), created the [Name Project](http://www.magdalenelaundries.com/name.htm) an attempt to document all the women who died in the Laundries.

The same organisation submitted a report, [State Involvement in the Magdalene Laundries](http://www.magdalenelaundries.com/Magdalene_Laundries_state_interaction_section_Final.pdf), which details from point 88 on how 155 bodies of women were moved from one unmarked grave in Drumcondra.

[Selection of survivor testimony](http://www.magdalenesurvivorstogether.net/#/survivor-testimony/4562712580)

There is also an hour-long documentary featuring interviews with survivors.
[Sex in a Cold Climate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSZ9i9NaUU4)

*Note: in this context, "girls institutions" and "laundries" mean the same thing. The laundries were the workshop component of girls institutions. However, in Ireland, these are colloquially referred to as Magdalen Laundries or "the Laundries".*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1926_Slavery_Convention

http://www.thejournal.ie/un-committee-against-torture-recommends-inquiry-into-magdalene-laundries-149691-Jun2011/

http://www.idcmagdalen.ie/en/MLW/Magdalen%20Rpt%20full.pdf/Files/Magdalen%20Rpt%20full.pdf

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/womens-politics/9878223/Irelands-Magdalene-Laundries-I-hope-my-birth-mother-can-now-rest-in-peace.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_to_Inquire_into_Child_Abuse

http://www.magdalenelaundries.com/name.htm

http://www.magdalenelaundries.com/Magdalene_Laundries_state_interaction_section_Final.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but you can't use things that happened in other institutions as evidence of things that happened in the laundries.

Comment: I'm not. The only thing missing from the Laundries (referred to as "girls institutions" in the conclusions)  is *systemic* sexual abuse. This differentiation is clear above.

Comment: Then you should remove the part that says " It doesn't particularly apply to the Laundries" and cite references that apply clearly to the laundries, and not 'institutions' in general.

Comment: I've added a note at the end, hopefully this should remove the ambiguity.

Comment: What evidence do you have that 'girls institutions' refers only to laundries? There were certainly other institutions for girls, and the report refers to 'institutions run by the state', which the laundries weren't.

Comment: Even your quotes are not referring to the laundries. They refer to "The Reformatory and Industrial Schools" and " boys’ institutions". In fact all of the paragraphs you quote are wholesale from Wikipedia and about general child abuse.

Comment: It's actually fairly tricky to find first-hand accounts online, but I'm adding some testimony from a website, and a documentary which originally aired on Channel 4, featuring interviews with victims.

Comment: That seems like a really weird definition for Slavery. Are you claiming all minors are slaves? Slavery does not really make sense when you are referring to Governments. Whole classes of people are "enslaved" by governments, we just call that legal guardianship. When people are deemed unable to look after themselves, the state either recognized the legal right of the parents to do so, does so itself, or finds some other entity to do so. Great injustices can and do happen in all of these situations, but they are not slavery just socialism.

Comment: Please read my answer again and follow some of the links. I think you might be going off half-cocked here.